# Click event not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I have a problem with click event:

I have in HTML:

```
<div class="content-block cards-clipboard">
                        <a class="download-all">Download All</a>

                        </div>
```

And a JS:

```
var html = '<div class="card demo-card-header-pic data-url='+img+'">'+
  '<div style="background-image:url('+thumb+'); background-size: 100%; height: 272px; background-repeat: no-repeat;" valign="bottom" class="card-header color-white no-border">'+html_icone_camera+'</div>'+
  '<div class="card-content">'+
    '<div class="card-content-inner">'+
     '<p class="color-gray">Postado em '+datapub+'</p>'+
      '<p>'+legenda+'</p>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="card-footer-'+id_link+'">'+
    '<button data-url='+img+' data-step="download" data-cod='+id_link+' type="button" class="download-imagem btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block '+id_link+'"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbspDownload</button>'+
  '</div>'+
'</div>';

$$(html).appendTo('.cards-clipboard');
```

And a trigger:

```
$$('.download-all').on('click', function() {
                $$("button[data-step='download']").click();

            });
```

That is: I have a button ('.download-all') when clicked, trigger a click in other buttons generated dinamically via `append` (var html) that have the data-step=download attribute.

However, when i click in .download-all button, the **first** button not receive a click - only the first button - the others, receive....

I appreciate any help

**EDIT**: If i put `$$("button[data-step='download']").click();` in console, the clicks works fine in all buttons....

Comment: Could you add your generated html after you have finished appending to `.cards-clipboard`?

Comment: Remove de ' from download. It should be `$$("button[data-step=download]").click();`

Comment: @MarceloMyara still not working :(

Comment: Another modification that I would try: if you just want to run any binded handler to the "click" event of those buttons, I would use `$$("button[data-step=download]").triggerEvent('click');` instead of `click()`

Comment: this will prevent the "automatic" behaviors associated with the click on a button, and will only run the onClick handler (which appears to me that you bind in somewhere else to those buttons)

Comment: Same issue with triggerEvent... If i paste $$("button[data-step='download']").click(); on console, the clicks works fine...

Comment: Hey, I would suggest that you strip down the HTML and JS files just to the minimum related to that issue and test it. If it persists, upload it to a fiddle or on your question here so we can try to reproduce. The problem may be lying somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, remove 2 $ signs and only have one:

```
$(html).appendTo('.cards-clipboard');
```

And your event command would be:

```
$('.download-all').on('click', function() {
            $("button[data-step='download']").trigger('click');

        });
```

Comment: There is no difference between `$$` and `$` in jQuery. But I would suggest just one, as it's "standard".

Comment: I never said there is difference but it makes the code more confusing.

Comment: Because the click event is nothing. First define something for it and then, you may be able to get something out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use JQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
 $$('.download-all').on('click', function() {
            $$("button[data-step='download']").trigger("click");

 });
```

If not try to remove the double dollar sign and use single dollar sign.

Please vote and mark the solution if useful.

**Thanks!**

Comment: trigger("click") give me same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Only the first button is being triggered because of page loading order. php is executed before html/javascript. Because this happens, the event handler can't find a button with specified id or class. One way to circumvent this is to delegate an event listener to the area which contains the dynamically created buttons. For instance,

```
$('#myId').delegate('button','click',function() {
       //do something
});
```